# Is the Drapers point inaccurate?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, thermal-radiation, frequency

Is the Drapers point faulty since an oven glows visibly red without it actually reaching Drapers point? When the Drapers point blackbody radiation frequency is calculated by Wien's law it results about 82.57 terahertz, while the frequency range of visible light is around 400 THz to 790 THz. So is it faulty?

Wien's law:

$$ \lambda = \frac bT\,.$$

So the $\lambda$ (wavelength) was 3631 nanometers wavelength and its corresponding frequency is 82.57 THz.

Comment: Is it a glitch in the matrix?

Comment: This question is already answered on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draper_point. The article notes that though Wien's law predicts a peak frequency that's invisible to the human eye, the blackbody spectrum includes light at other frequencies, and there's enough visible light in the tail of the spectrum for the object to visibly glow.

Comment: Thanks @user196574. But is there an equation that tells us the extreme of the extreme peak of the wave? and how much light is emitted in that extreme of the extreme peak

Comment: @ScienceAJ the equation is [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law). You could integrate it over the visible range to see how much is emitted in the visible range at a given temperature.

Comment: Thanks @Mauricio.

Comment: But is it compatible with Wien's Law?

Comment: If possible Please try to post a full-fledged answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planck's law describes the emission of an ideal blackbody, given in frequency ($\nu$) form as
$$B(\nu,T)=\frac{2h}{c^2}\nu^3n(\nu,T)\;,$$
where $T$ is the temperature and $n(\nu,T)=1/(\exp(h\nu/k_{\rm B}T)-1)$ is the Bose-Einstein distribution.

If you look for the maximum peak ($dB/d\nu=0$), you will find Wien's law:
$\nu=b T$, where $b=0.058$ THz/T. However this is just the peak position, the actual distribution is broad and can reach the visible spectrum even when the peak is outside the visible spectrum, like in Draper's point.

Here is a log-linear graph of the distribution for different temperatures

[image]

Note that the peak for all the temperatures shown here is in the infrared and not in the visible, yet at least some have a contribution in the visible.

According to a quick Google search (please verify), the human eye can detect at minimum $10^{-10}$ W/m${}^2$. We can integrate the curves above to obtain the intensity over the visible range, we get:

- 300 K, integrated intensity (visible): $10^{-19}$ W/m${}^2$.
- 798 K (Draper's point); integrated intensity (visible):  $0.064$ W/m${}^2$.
- 1000 K, integrated intensity (visible):  $10$ W/m${}^2$.

We can see that at Draper's point, the intensity in the visible is clearly over the human eye threshold. We have to consider that this is not a purely physical matter, it is also a biological question, that's why probably Drapers point is determined empirically. A more precise theoretical calculation is more complicated as it depends on the size of the eye, the human eye response to red, blue, green and so on.

Comment: Thanks, @Mauricio

Comment: @ScienceAJ I updated my answer, I was using the wrong Draper limit.

Comment: Thanks, You were actually right except the 525  K(elvin) should be 525 C(elcius)